# Looking for a BNF to DFA conversion tool

Tags: compiler-construction, bnf, dfa

Is there a tool that can receive BNF grammar as input and produce a DFA from it?
I have already found the 'hackingoff' tool in here: http://hackingoff.com/

But it is more of a testing tool and does not work on large grammars.

Comment: What you found doesn't turn BNF into DFA (for reasons explained in the answer). The only thing it does with BNF grammars is do some preprocessing needed for LL(1) parsers. The DFAs are generated by the lexer generator and the regex implementation. Reading comprehension helps ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DFAs do not have sufficient power to implement context-free parsers, e.g., what you can express with BNF.  There is no such tool.

The specified website does not offer any such tool, either.

Comment: Exactly. +1 What you should be looking for is a BNF to DPDA conversion.